# Getting NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost: -1005 in my app when getting response data from db

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm getting this error (not all the time but several times) while getting response -which may contain large amount of data- from database in my ios app. Here is the case

I opened the menu that i will parse data, while response data is being downloaded, i put my app to background and opened Facebook app and then i went back to my app and got this error. (I have SSL Pinning in my app.)

Does iOS stop secure connection and start another in the same time, or maintain current and start another?

Is there any advice that I should follow?

Comment: Have you enabled background for your app ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.